# How do you treats ants in a raised Hügulkultur bed?

Tags: pests, ants, hugelkultur

I have a raised bed that's 2 feet tall, by 12 feet long, by 3 feet wide. This bed is totally infested ants and it took only one week! The bed was constructed with hugulkulture principles, the bottom layer is logs, then sticks, then decomposed leaf mold, then leaf mold treated with organic compost. This is a pretty popular method done by many YouTubers.

I should have seen this coming, I live in Texas. How can I get these guys out of there? I'm assuming the ant bed is two feet tall, as I can see it coming out the top of the raised bed.

Comment: And I know that you're a hugelkulturalist, but be aware that there is absolutely no science behind its use. See here for one article: https://www.gardenmyths.com/hugelkultur-gardening-hugelkultur-raised-beds/. There are many others... As a professor once told me, "In nature, wood decomposes on TOP of the ground, not in it." Removing the wood will remove your ant problem.

Comment: @Jurp you should tell your professor about roots. =P

Comment: AH, but roots aren't deadfall, which is what you're burying. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without using pesticides, the only way to remove the ants is to remove the wood in the bed, because that's where they're living. They may eventually move into the raised bed's wooden sides, assuming that you used wood for those.

Do not use insecticides in a vegetable garden.